# htaccess not working on WHM

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, whm

I'm trying to run an PHP application on such this type of link http://XXX.xxx.xxx.xxx/~sender0/
I'm using htaccess file

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l




RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?action=$1 [NC,L]


</IfModule>
```

the system replying the htaccess error.
I think as the URL have a special character "~" this may the reason of not working my application.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to add following code before RewriteCond lines and check it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~sender0/
```

Comment: nope not working, when i used my old htaccess then there was showing htaccess error but while using new one, then it is not replying anything